# How do I fix a conflict between two columns with the same name?

Tags: site-column

We created a custom column and named it "Language". As you may know there is already Base column with the same name, but this should have not been an issue.

The issue is though - when I go to Site columns - clicking the base column - it opens up the custom column we created.

However, when I create doc libs and add these two columns - these look separate and work fine.

Comment: Do you mean you created a new site column or an ad-hoc column in the list? And are you sure you haven't accidentally modified the site column, thinking you were looking at the custom column?
A bit more detail about the steps would help.

Comment: used WSP to deploy new columns with unique GUID's but same name; at that point base Language column "merged" with "custom" language column....

Comment: Okay, there was no way to tell that from the question.

Comment: Note - the situation has been corrected, by deleting duplicate custom column and adding new one.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder how did you manage to add duplicate Language column to your site columns since it is not possible to add them trough UI (the column reserved message will appear). 
If you added your Language column directly on list then your new column will be added but it internal name will be Language0 (but by default design this column will be not added to Site columns).

When you click Language column under Site Columns you can check URL for your internal column name. It should contain querystring `field=Language`. This is the only way you can be sure you are editing the right column.

Suggestion:

When adding new columns to your site avoid using reserved names (there are some mechanisms to prevent you doing so but obviously they are not 100% working). The problem you are now experiencing is just 'the tip of the iceberg'. If you really need to use reserved name and if you are using UI to add columns do this:

- Add new column and in Column name type name you know that is not reserved (in your case name it myLanguage or something similar). This will become your column internal name.
- Edit your new column and choose some other name for it (eg. Language). Your internal name will stay myLanguage but column Display Name will change.

Comment: the column was added as WSP feature... using unique GUID but same name; what is q\weird another column - Author was added in same manner and no issues

Comment: Like I said, try to avoid reserved names and be sure internal names of columns you are deploying to be unique. I am always using something like XY_ColumName (where XY is project abbreviation) for internal names.

Comment: I assumed they were doing it through the UI as well. Deploying in a solution package is a whole different story - tricky enough without using an existing column name. I agree - try to avoid doing it.